# Excel - How to find a cell somewhere in another worksheet

Tags: excel

I need to find a cell, in another worksheet, by its value. The problem is, I can't use MATCH or LOOKUP as I this value can be anywhere in the worksheet. Is there an option to do so without VBA?

Thanks,

Comment: If your question is "is there an option to do this without programming" then it is per definition off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Lundin he asked without VBA. Formulas are still part of the Excel tag here as far as I know.

Comment: What is the output you would require? The coordinates of the cell?

Comment: @Jorvik77 Yep I need the cell coordinates

Comment: This is helpful https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array.html